# Backbone.js: Add validation to every model

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this, and would love some guidance.

I have an admin crud app where I would like to validate all models in a similar fashion. The code I'm using for validation works fine when I use it in a validate function:

```
var ModelName = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // ...
    validate: function (attrs) {
        // stuff happens
        return errors;
    }
});
```

However, I want to use the validation on every model, and don't want to repeat myself with the same code in every model.

How can I extend the Backbone Model to include this validate function on every model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily by "subclassing", say for instance,

```
var Validatable = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function (attrs) {
        // stuff happens
        return errors;
    }
});

var ModelOne = Validatable.extend({
   ...
});

var ModelTwo = Validatable.extend({
   ...
});
```

Alternatively, you still base on `Backbone.Model` and use `_.extend` directly.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. Trying now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the great solution @ggozad has shown you always can move the *validate logic* to a shared function like:

```
var Utils = {}
Utils.validateSomething = function( attributes ){
  // stuff happens
  return errors;
}

var ModelName = Backbone.Model.extend({
  validate: Utils.validateSomething
});
```

You still have to replicate the `validate` line in every Class but I think is DRY enough.

Comment: Awesome, I like this as well. Thanks!